# Is it possible to launch an aspx ( asp.net ) page by clicking on a ribbon button?

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

Can I have a ribbon button launch an aspx ( asp.net ) page? The aspx page needs to inherit authentication and authorization as the logged in Dynamics user.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute custom JavaScript from a ribbon button allowing you to spin up a new browser window pointing at whatever you like.

To inherit security credentials you need to look at setting up federated authentication across both the CRM server and the custom website hosting the ASPX.  As you can probably imagine this isn't a trivial task.

You could also look at dropping your website into the custom ISV folder as was the case with CRM 4.  However, this approach **has been deprecated** in CRM 2011 and AFAIK is therefore no longer supported.

As @Konrad pointed out you won't be able to use the Data Service REST API (OData) from your custom web pages as the service is only accessible from web resources hosted within the CRM environment.  Server-side you'll be fine against the Org Service.

If you can get away with doing what you need in a web resource I'd highly recommend it as it's a whole lot less work.

Comment: both of these are approaches you can use; and both are ones I've seen clients of mine use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that. A while ago, I put in an iframe that I linked to an outside web page and it worked as supposed to **except** for connecting to the organization data. I just couldn't make that work (I got impatient, to be honest and didn't try all too hard).

The resolution I deployed in the end was to run a web resource, which was run internally on the server, that communicated the data to an outside service.

I'm assuming that the same behavior will follow if you try to open windows/convey data in to/out from the CRM.

Comment: When you say that "the web resource runs internally on the server", I believe that although it is stored on the server but that it actually executes on the client. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. What I meant is that you can populate IFRAME component from a web resource (internally run) or from a page from outside the CRM (externally run).